# PostgreSQL sql function syntax error while writing function

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, sql-update

I am trying to write a Postgres function. I am doing it for the first time so don't feel annoyed if you find some silly mistakes:

```
CREATE  FUNCTION proc_test(userId int)
returns void 
begin
UPDATE pl_payroll SET remarks =viw.remarks from pl_payroll   
diff,viwPayDifference viw 
where diff.userid = cast(userId as varchar); 
end;
```

It is giving an error like

> syntax error at or near "begin"

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SQL` functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-sql.html) don't have `BEGIN` and `END` like [`plpgsql` functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql.html).

```
CREATE FUNCTION proc_test(userId int)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
UPDATE pl_payroll
SET    remarks = viw.remarks
FROM   pl_payroll diff, viwPayDifference viw
WHERE  diff.userid = cast(userId as varchar);
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Your `UPDATE` also looks **wrong** per se.

- There is no WHERE condition joining `pl_payroll` to the additional tables.
- You don't need to join in `pl_payroll` a second time.
- The second occurrence of `userId` is not table-qualified and probably ambiguous.

Check out the [`UPDATE` syntax in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html). Should be something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION proc_test(userId int)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
UPDATE pl_payroll p
SET    remarks = viw.remarks
FROM   viwPayDifference viw
WHERE  viw.userid = p.userId::varchar;
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

As an aside: It looks highly suspicious that you have to cast `diff.userId` to `varchar`. Something off with your data types in your base tables?